# Monitor RabbitMQ nodes via JConsole

Tags: performance, rabbitmq, activemq-classic, monitoring, jconsole

We are doing R & D on RabbitMQ and ActiveMQ, now we want to measure CPU and Memory consumption by particular MQ.

For ActiveMQ we found good support with JConsole and working as expected,
but we are unable to find out JConsole support RabbitMQ.

Can anyone please give me some head up to test RabbitMQ with JConsole.
If not possible with JConsole than suggest some alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JConsole is a Java tool, RabbitMQ is written in Erlang.

In order to monitor RabbitMQ you can use the  [`Management UI`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html)

you can enable it using:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

> The web UI is located at: http://server-name:15672/ The HTTP API and
>   its documentation are both located at: http://server-name:15672/api/
>   (or view our latest HTTP API documentation here).

Have a look also a this plugin https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-top